# Как получить доступ к элементу класса из внутреннего класса?

Tags: c++

Делаю двоичное дерево поиска, которое хранит функцию сравнения элементов `cmp`. При попытке использовать ее во внутреннем классе `iterator` меня информируют:

> C2327: tree::cmp не является именем типа, статическим членом или перечислителем.

```
template <
    /* code */
    typename Compare = std::less<>
> class tree {

    struct node;
    using pointer = std::shared_ptr<node>;

    /* code */

    Compare cmp{};

    class iterator {

        pointer current;

        void next_parent(pointer& leaf)
        {
            if (!leaf->parent)
                return;
            else if (cmp(leaf, leaf->parent))        // error
                leaf = leaf->parent;
            else
                leaf = next_parent(leaf->parent);
        }

    public:

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            if (current->right)
                current = current->right;
            else
                next_parent(current);
            return *this;
        }

        /* code */

    };

    /* code */

};
```

Как получить доступ к этой нестатической `cmp`?

Comment: Очевидно, у итератора должна быть ссылка на `tree`, получаемая в конструкторе.

Comment: @VladD Я прошу прощения, ссылка `tree& tree_ref` и конструктор `iterator(const tree& tree_ref) : tree_ref{ tree_ref } {}`?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, да.

Comment: Класс `tree::iterator` не имеет никакого отношения к классу `tree`. Оно просто объявлен внутри, а во всем остальном - это просто независимые классы. Чтобы `tree::iterator` мог доступиться к нестатическому члену `tree::cmp` класс `tree::iterator` должен иметь на руках некий экземпляр класса `tree`, через который он и будет доступаться к `cmp`. Без экземпляра и доступаться не к чему.

Comment: @VladD я пытаюсь создать итератор: `iterator{ this }`, но получается _невозможно преобразовать initializer list в tree::iterator_

Comment: @lisovskey: А если `*this`? Это ж всё-таки ссылка.

Comment: @VladD То же самое

Comment: @lisovskey: А если круглые скобки? (Я не сильно хорошо разобрался в тонкостях семантики миллиона различных способов создания объекта в C++.)

Comment: @VladD Ой, еще раз прошу прощения, после изменения на `*this` все встало на места, это было из-за остальных параметров

Comment: @lisovskey: А, ну слава богу. Ну тогда вроде бы вопрос решён.

Comment: @AnT: А почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD на всякий случай семантика фигурных скобок: _An aggregate is an array or a class with no user-provided constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions_

Comment: @lisovskey: Кстати, я не уверен, `const tree&` или `tree&`. Имеет ли право изменяться `tree` в течение жизненного цикла итератора? // Хотя стоп, семантика `const` не требует, чтобы объект реально не менялся. Отбой воздушной тревоги!

Comment: @VladD нет, я ему запертил

Comment: @lisovskey: Ага, спасибо, буду знать.